# Pushwoosh crashing on registration on Android 5.0.2

Tags: android, cordova, pushwoosh

A colleague in the office is facing the following situation: He downloaded a sample code from the below link to get familiar with pushwoosh functionality: https://github.com/Pushwoosh/phonegap-build-sample-app 
This example is built using Adobe PhoneGap online: https://build.phonegap.com
Although this example works fine in the iOS devices, it crashes on execution when on Android devices, both in version 4.4.2 and 5.0.2. Doing step-by-step code execution with weinre he noticed the application crashes on device registration. He wonders if he should try a different example or a different plugin.  Could a wrong Google API key cause this behavior?

PhoneGap (iOS / Android / Windows)
cli-5.2.0 (3.9.1 / 4.1.1 / 3.8.1)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

For Phonegap Build please use "pushwoosh-pgb-plugin". PGB are way too slow updating Android libraries :(